# Convert Lambda expressions that contains variable to string

Tags: c#, lambda

I want to convert flowing expression

```cs
person.Name = "John";
Expression<Func<Person, bool>> exp = x => x.Name == person.Name && x.Age > 20;
```

to string like this:

`(x.Name == "John") AndAlso (x.Age > 20)`

I use `exp.ToString();` method but the result is:

`(x.Name == value(MyNamespace.MyClass+<>c__DisplayClass0).person.Name) AndAlso (x.Age > 20)`

How can i convert expression correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that your expression references a variable from scope in a closure, and what you need is a constant expression.

You can rewrite the expression tree with an `ExpressionVisitor` so it eliminates memeber accesses leading to a constant:

```
namespace FixVisitor
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var person = new Person();
            person.Name = "John";

            Expression<Func<Person, bool>> exp = x => x.Name == person.Name && x.Age > 20;

            var modified = new FixVisitor().Visit(exp);
            Console.WriteLine(modified);
        }
    }

    class FixVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        bool IsMemeberAccessOfAConstant(Expression exp)
        {
            if (exp.NodeType == ExpressionType.MemberAccess)
            {
                var memberAccess = (MemberExpression) exp;
                if (memberAccess.Expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.Constant)
                    return true;
                return IsMemeberAccessOfAConstant(memberAccess.Expression);
            }

            return false;
        }

        protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
        {
            if (IsMemeberAccessOfAConstant(node) && node.Type == typeof(string))
            {
                var item = Expression.Lambda<Func<string>>(node);
                var value = item.Compile()();
                return Expression.Constant(value, typeof(string));
            }

            return base.VisitMember(node);
        }
    }

    class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've updated the answer slightly so it can work with original expression directly, not requiring a special method call inside the expression.

Answer (score 1):

To do what you want, you have to treat person.Name as constant, so I think that you have to build the Expression at runtime:

```
var pers = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Person), "x"); //The parameter to the expression(its type and its name)
var propName = Expression.Property(pers, "Name"); // The property "Name" of the parameter(x.Name)
var nameAsConstant = Expression.Constant(person.Name); // The value I will compare to x.Name
var equal = Expression.Equal(propName, nameAsConstant); // The comparison(x.Name == "John")
var propAge = Expression.Property(pers, "Age"); // The property "Age" of the parameter(x.Age)
var ageConstant = Expression.Constant(20); // The value I will compare to x.Age
var greater = Expression.GreaterThan(propAge, ageConstant); // The comparison(x.Age > 20)
var conditions = Expression.AndAlso(equal, greater); // Merging the expression with && [(x.Name == "John") AndAlso (x.Age > 20)]
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Person, bool>>(conditions, pers); // Build the expression
var lambdaStr = lambda.ToString(); //x => ((x.Name == "John") AndAlso (x.Age > 20))
```

If you need only `((x.Name == "John") AndAlso (x.Age > 20))` just do `conditions.ToString();`